# Getting position of last child div within slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the Dragend plugin to turn a series of web pages into slides. My HTML looks something like this:

```
<main id="swipe-page">
    <div class="dragend-page">
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragend-page">
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragend-page">
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Some slides are larger than others, so I am trying to manually adjust the height using jQuery as the plugin just gives each slide a ridiculously large height.

To attempt to do this, I am first getting the correct dragend-page slide by running this command:

```
$('.dragend-page').eq(this.page)
```

Now I need to get the position of the last page-content div. I attempted to do this:

```
$('.dragend-page').eq(this.page).children(".page-content").last()
```

But it's not returning anything. $('.dragend-page').eq(this.page) is not returning an object.

*this.page* returns the current slide (dragend-page div) the user is on

So how would I manually adjust the height? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: $('.dragend-page').last().children(".page-content").last()?

Comment: What does `this.page` return?

Comment: this.page returns the current slide (dragend-page div) the user is on

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. You didn't answer my question: what does it return? Example.

Comment: why/how is it wrong? It's my JS that must be wrong.

Comment: `class="page-content"` you are missing end quotes.

Comment: @Tushar That will only get me the last page-content div in the last dragend-page slide. I need to get the last page-content div for the users current dragend-page slide

Comment: @MrUpsidown Nice catch. I only typed that up quickly for this question - my actual HTML is correct with real content inside of it.

Comment: Replace `eq(this.page)` by `eq(0)` or `eq(1)` and you will see it works.

Comment: `(this.page).children(".page-content").last()` this will work if `this.page ` is current page jquery object